# In Safari browser, How to open keyboard, when I trigger focusing in a input box

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

A Input box has a click event.
Tap buttons have trigger event that make focusing a input box in order.
Whenever click tap buttons, select a input box in order.
but, On IOS, It is not open the keyboard. It is just focusing input box.

for example....
Tab button...

```
btn.on('click', function() {
    input.trigger('click');
});
```

input box....

```
input.on('click', function(){
    $(this).focus();
    .....something codes......
});
```

On Android, The keyboard opens when it's in focus. But, IOS...It is not.

I also tried to 'touchstart event' instead of 'click'. But It was not working.

Help......

I want it to be available in all environments.

Answer (score 0):

```
let idView = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let idView = NSView(frame: viewRect)
idView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This is a example in Swift. You can set your input View to becomeFirstResponder to make the keyboard show.